# A set $\,\{0,1\}^*$ is countable , but its subset $\,\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}\,$ is uncountable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I think $\{0,1\}^*$ represents all $0,1$-sequences, and $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is the $0,1$-sequences with infinite length. So $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is a subset of $\{0,1\}^*$.
$\{0,1\}^*$ is countable, while $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ is uncountable.

It's really strange, because I can count the whole set and cannot when it comes to its subset!
I don't know how to understand it. Who can save me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are wrong, $\{0,1\}^*$ does represent all _finite_ 0, 1-sequences, so the set $\{0, 1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ of _infinite_ 0, 1-sequencces isn't a subset of it. No contradiction here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The set of all $0$-$1$ sequences is uncountable. $\{0,1\}^*$ more commonly means the set of *finite* $0$-$1$ sequences, which is countable.

Comment: Why it's not countable? we can count it in this way:  1 - 0, 2 - 1, 3 - 00, 4 - 01, 5 - 10, 6 - 11 , 7 - 000, 8 - 001, 9 - 010...

Comment: @Sayakiss What Chris means is, you have misunderstood the definition of $\{0,1\}^\ast$. $\{0,1\}^\ast$ is the set of all *finite* 0-1 sequences. Sequences of infinite length are not included. So $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is **not** a subset of $\{0,1\}^\ast$. In fact, the two sets are disjoint. Now $\{0,1\}^\ast$ is countable, but $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is not.